# numpy ArrayMemoryError with converting column to str

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a medium sized csv file, about 100MB. It contains 20,000 rows.

For some reason I cannot do the following operation:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-52:~/sunshine(XXX)$ python
Python 3.10.5 (main, Oct  1 2022, 00:47:42) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('/home/ubuntu/XXX_dataset__full.csv')
>>> df.memory_usage()
Index          128
url         160000
FOO         160000
BAR         160000
text        160000
dtype: int64
>>> docs = df['text'].values.astype(str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 256. GiB for an array with shape (20000,) and data type <U3430166
>>> quit()
```

Available RAM on my ubuntu:

```
MemTotal:       129196996 kB
```

Why is numpy estimating so much memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"and data type <U3430166" indicates that you've got at least one row with a 3430166-character string in the `text` column. NumPy string arrays need to allocate the same amount of space for every row, at 4 bytes per character, so it needs to allocate 3430166*4 bytes for *every single row* of the 20000-row array you're trying to create. That's about 256 GiB, or 274 GB, over twice your available RAM.

Note that your original dataframe's `text` column is not backed by a NumPy string array. It's backed by an object array, holding references to ordinary Python string objects. By default, `memory_usage` will not report memory consumed by the string objects.